# How to export varchar(max) columns from table to Excel 2007 in SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, ssis-2012

I have package which creates staging tables on production and populates data in it. Later i need to export those tables data into Excel 2007 Files.

Here, one column in table is of datatype: nvarchar(max). When I am trying to Export that table into excel using [Data Flow Task] with [OLEDB Source] for table and [Excel Destination] for Excel, it is giving me an error like below.

```
Error: Cannot create an OLE DB accessor. Verify that the column metadata is valid.
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried using a Data Conversion or Derived Column step and explicitly converting the column to a Unicode Text datatype?

Answer (score 1):

first try setting  Setting "Validate External Metadata" to false

if it doesnt work

, instead of   using a OleDB source use  .Net Source, where this bug doesn't happen.